# Keep most recent document version in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to store **billions** of documents in `mongodb` very efficienty by the following conditions, all documents has a `unique id` and `document time` field:

1- insert document if the `unique id` is not exist(new document).

2- In the case a document with `unique id` exists in the collection, check the `document time field`, the most recent documnt should keep in the collection.
So in this case if received document is newer(by checking `document time field`) should replaced with the stored one, and else if received document is older than stored one should be ignored, and keep the stored one.

I know that I can use some find, update, insert queries with if statements in my code to do this.

But I want to know is there any better solution, structure, feature to use, to do this task more efficienty for billions data that continually increasing by the time?

Comment: Have you tried update with a pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of in-built `if` `else` or `switch` operator provided by `MongoDB` in this case

```
db.test.updateOne({
    uniqueId: "UniqueIdGoesHere" // criteria to match
}, [{      // aggregation pipleline with $set stage and $cond operator 
    $set: {
        time: { $cond:[ { $lt: [ "$time", new Date('2021-10-17T16:54:05.170Z')] }, new Date(), "$time"] } // condition to check if input date is larger than stored one, simply replaced else keep old
    }
}], {
    upsert: true
})
```